# Proper way to transfer SSL certificates to my PC from GC new SSL certificate?

Tags: mysql-workbench, google-cloud-sql

Google Cloud SQL supplies SSL certificates.   I copied them individually onto MS word and used them as "path"
destination to the queries of mysql workbench.   The connection fails.   I have proper names: server-ca.pem; cbossl-key.pem and cbossl-cert.pem.   Google in "access control"  where new ssl is turned on, I used the name "cbossl-cert.pem".  This is the same name given to the copy of ssl to my PC word.   Kindly help me to identify my   error in using ssl.   The document suffix .doc - it is not
acceptable doc for the path designation?   If so, how do I do?

Comment: What does MS Word have to do with it? You only have to copy *files* around.

Answer (score 1):

MS Word doc format is not a valid format for SSL certificates and keys. MySQL clients expect these files to be as they are (Plain text with no formatting at all). My advice is

1. Create a new client key and cert on "SSL Certificates" section in the instance's "Access Control" tab on Developers Console.
2. Download the Client key ("Download client-key.pem"), the client ("Download client-cert.pem") and the server ("Download server-cert.pem") certificates and save them as they are into known locations.
3. Click on the "Restart and Close" button
4. Configure your MySQL workbench to use the files you downloaded at 2.

Comment: Dear Antonio:  Great to suggest right way.   Do I use my ssl name as certificate file name prefix?  or simply copy such as client-key.pem and etc.?   Downloading - doesn't need a file name?    I guess you are suggesting the file name of the downloads prefix to be client?  Thanking a great deal in advance!!

Comment: When you click in the Download link for each of the 3 files, you will see a different "Save As" or "Open with" kind of dialog. You can use the suggested names or use something else. You beware of the choosen names for each one and their location, and configure them accordingly in your Workbench.